# Inserting blob in oracle using php pdo

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle11g

I have to insert blob in oracle view. In ths case there is no opportunity to use this EMPTY_BLOB() with returning clause. Like this:
"Insert into table (a,b,c) values (a,b, EMPTY_BLOB()) RETURNING c into :photo"
Becouse RETURING doesn`t work in views
I need a method to create empty blob before inserting data, but i don`t know how to do it with PDO.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried inserting into the underlying tables?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP connected to ORA DB I have recently solved a problem with inserting of `CLOB` which should be treated the same way.

In my case it was enough to insert the data as characters while when binding I set the length of characters as length of bind. But You can try to use a function `TO_BLOB()`, that needs an input casted to a `RAW`:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_blob_table (my_blob_column) VALUES (TO_BLOB(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('some binary data as string')))
```

or also a universal `TO_LOB()` should work (converts to `CLOB` or `BLOB` depending on source/target column):

```sql
INSERT INTO my_blob_table (my_blob_column) VALUES (TO_LOB('some binary data as string'))
```

**EDIT:** Using google I found these should work:

- if we have a `long` column that we want to convert to `clob/blob`:

```sql
create table t1 (id int, my_blob blob);
create table t2 (id int, my_long long);
insert into t2 values (1, rpad('*',4000,'*'));
insert into t1 select id, to_lob(my_long) from t2;
```

- if we have a `long raw` column that we want to convert to `blob`:

```sql
create table t1 (id int, my_blob blob);
create table t2 (id int, my_long_raw long raw);
insert into t2 values (1, rpad('*',4000,'*'));
insert into t1 select id, to_blob(my_long_raw) from t2;
```

That should work... See [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:13213885403654) and [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:510622111991).

Comment: Seems that i could`t use your sollution. Becouse my column is long, so I can bind only PDO::PARAM_LOB data type to be inserted there, but long data connot be converted with cast_to_raw :(

Comment: Then try the same without casting. If You have `LONG` type of data then there should be no problem with casting of `LONG` to `BLOB` using `TO_BLOB` nor `TO_LOB`.

Comment: strange, but it doesn`t work too. I have error: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Comment: Hmm and why can't You convert the `LONG` column into a `BLOB` column? `LONG` is kinda outdated... Or at least convert Your `LONG` to `LONG RAW` and then call `TO_BLOB(your_long_raw_data)`. Cannot think of better way...

Comment: @Maxim I added some examples that should work. Notice the difference between `to_lob` and `to_blob`...